# Activating script via button press on embedded Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, iframe, google-sheets, embed

I am trying to embed a Google Spreadsheet that has a script I'd like users to be able to activate. I don't want them to be able to edit anything on the page.

I thought I could do this by

- Share sheet and set to edit permissions
- Restrict editing on the one sheet I want to share (the images sit above the cells, so I thought this would prevent people from editing cells but allow them to click on the button
- Publish to the web
- Embed the sheet

Here is the iframe I used:

```
<iframe width="1250" height=1000 src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRRajy1TK9Y9YQg-Df3bwTy9ktxPECq6T5gS7UfkrYpV_osxwDwRuQClC168B8-o4KsCdFl4kfMYtau/pubhtml?gid=1796260078&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false"></iframe>
```

For context the scripts hide or show different rows. Clicking "show game 2" hides a section of rows and "show game 1" unhides these rows.

The sheet embeds okay but isn't interactable. I have turned off the restricted editing to test (it's back on) and that didn't allow people to edit anything, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

#### Workaround:

- Use a another button outside the embedded spreadsheet instead.
- Publish a headless web-app from your sheet using `doPost()`
- On Button click, use JavaScript to post from your website to apps script web-app
- On receiving post request, hide/show the rows using your original script.

#### References:

- [Web-app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Comment: thanks for this workaround! Unfortunately, the site that I am trying to embed on only allows me to input custom HTML and JS isn't allowed.Here is the page for reference https://www67.myfantasyleague.com/2019/home/42642#2

Comment: @Bricky You might be able to leverage `doGet()` to send sheet as a table in html.