# Running an Apps Script function from within a sheet embedded in a webpage

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, velo

I have a Google Sheet embedded in a Wix webpage using the Google Drive App developed by Wix.
On a sheet is button to which a Apps Script function is assigned.
When the button is pressed the script runs but returns the error message :
'Script TryThis experienced an error' with the details offered saying the same.

Is it possible to run an Apps Script function from within a website and if so how?

Comment: If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

**Embedding a Google Sheet would change the access of the File**

If you publish or embed a Google Sheet to a website (HTML) it would be available for view only. This means that the App Script would not run correctly due to not being able to perform edits to the file due to the way it has been added to Wix.

The App Script would experience the error due to being unable to have edit access to the spreadsheet itself when being embedded.

**Suggested Workarounds:**

- Publish the App Script as a Web App and make the calls to make the edits from it.
- If possible under Wix, you can `POST` from your website and receive it in `doPost()` from App Script.
- Add another button that would be embedded outside the Sheet, you can review the thread regarding this particular workaround[(over the website)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64448580/google-apps-script-not-working-in-an-embedded-iframe).

**References:**

- [Activating script via button press on embedded Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60118984/activating-script-via-button-press-on-embedded-google-sheet)