# Scripts are not executing for users with reader permission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have added an image on my grid, and assign script to it. But script executes only when I click on image, and when another user(with reader permission) clicks on image nothing happens. The same situation is with `onOpen()` trigger - nothing happens when user whith reader permission opens the grid. I understand that editor permission will fix it, but I don't need the user to be able to edit the table, I only need that user be able click buttons(image)/get alive triggers/menus that i create, but not edit anything manually. How can i do this(may be i should give some extended reader permission, or to turn on something in GAS project)?

Answer (score 1):

When users execute a script for the first time, they will get an allow permissions prompt, so they can authorize the script to make changes on their behalf.

However, if the user has viewing permissions over the sheet or file, they cannot authorize the script to run or make changes on their behalf since they cannot make changes to the file. (I found a similar question, with the difference that the sheet was embedded in a website that has some information about why it does work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60118984/)).

And it's documented in the Apps Script documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#:%7E:text=that%20they%20have-,permission%20to%20edit.,-An%20installable%20edit):

> An installable open trigger runs when a user opens a spreadsheet, document, or form that they have permission to edit.

You can also request a feature request to Google asking for an option to allow users with "viewing permissions" to run scripts [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features).

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think you may give editor's permissions but protect the sheet/range so only you can edit them with this option -->

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cprotect-a-range-or-sheet

Let me know if this worked!

---

Option 2:

Adding to those protected ranges you can too create a Library with your functions in another spreadsheet (or in Google App Script independently) -> read about it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)

You can now set buttons/menus associated with those original functions, but I think that this can give you an altenative
For example:

```
function function1_toOrigin() {
 LibraryName.function1()
}
function function2_toOrigin() {
 LibraryName.function2()
}
```

Yes, they'll be able to access to these linking functions but nothing more, I think they won't be *that* unreliable??

IMPORTANT: If there are modifications to the script you should deploy them again as a new version of the library and update the version in your spreadsheet by double-clicking in your library

Comment: The permissions of the table editor also give the rights to edit/write/delete apps scripts, libs, etc. This is the point of the problem. I don't understand how such nonsense was allowed, but it is so=(

Comment: See the new edit ;)

Comment: Thanks, but there is still the same problem. Any user with edit permission can do what he want with apps scripts: delete library/add library/write his own script. I dont know how it could be possible, but there is not option to give permission only to edit just the table. Unthinkable...